# Compare and refine strings in separate columns with refinr package

Tags: r, string-matching, openrefine

A lot of my time is spend in merging two data frames on the country, municipality, name or party column. Now, it's the [`refinr` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/refinr/vignettes/refinr-vignette.html), a R port to OpenRefine, that comes in handy. Only I haven't figured out yet how to compare two of 'the same' columns and name the strings like I use `refinr` on a single vector. I'm not that experienced in R so maybe this sounds a little bit vague. Maybe my examples make things a bit clearer.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(refinr)

# I would like to add the values (and the right name's) of this example df...
df1 <- tribble(
  ~uid, ~name, ~value,
  "A", "Red", 13,
  "A", "violet", 145,
  "B", "Blue", 3,
  "B", "yellow", 56,
  "C", "yellow-purple", 789,
  "C", "green", 17
  )

# ...to the following df
df2 <- tribble(
  ~uid, ~name,
  "A", "red",
  "B", "blu",
  "C", "YellowPurple",
  "C", "green"
  )

# The following code of course produces NA values
df3 <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("uid", "name"))

# While the following is the desired outcome

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  uid   name           value
  <chr> <chr>          <dbl>
1 A     Red             13 
2 B     Blue             3
3 C     yellow-purple  789   
4 C     green           17
```

The `key_collision_merge()` and the `n_gram_merge()` work on strings in a single vector. My question is, can I compare and change strings between two columns instead of one?

If this is possible, it would safe me so much time!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best use of `refinr`, which serves mostly to harmonize the word spelling within a single column. What you want to do looks like a fuzzy join, and there is an [R package for that](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzyjoin/index.html). An example of use could be:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(fuzzyjoin)


df1 <- tribble(
  ~uid, ~name, ~value,
  "A", "Red", 13,
  "A", "violet", 145,
  "B", "Blue", 3,
  "B", "yellow", 56,
  "C", "yellow-purple", 789,
  "C", "green", 17
)

# ...to the following df
df2 <- tribble(
  ~uid, ~name,
  "A", "red",
  "B", "blu",
  "C", "YellowPurple",
  "C", "green"
)

df3 <- df2 %>%
  stringdist_left_join(df1,
                       distance_col = "dist", 
                       method='soundex') %>% 
  select(uid=uid.x, name=name.y, value)

df3
  # A tibble: 4 x 3
  uid   name          value
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl>
1 A     Red              13
2 B     Blue              3
3 C     yellow-purple   789
4 C     green            17
```

I used the soundex algorithm, but there are other methods, all based on the [stringdist package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringdist/stringdist.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
library(refinr)
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  bind_rows(df2, .id = "id") %>% 
  mutate(key=key_collision_merge(name)) %>% 
  split(.$id) %>% 
  inner_join(x=select(.[[1]],-id), y=select(.[[2]], uid, key), by=c("uid", "key"))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  uid   name          value key         
  <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <chr>       
1 A     Red             13. Red         
2 C     yellow-purple  789. YellowPurple
3 C     green           17. green
```

But `"blu"` is not recognized as `"blue"` by both `refiner` functions. So you could include a gsub to change this specific string by adding this line `mutate(name=gsub("blu","blue",name))`